# Error creating bean in Spring Transaction Manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

hi every body im creating a web app with Spring-MVc and hibernate and Spring Transaction

when i add @Repository to my class it make error:
the error is :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'numberGeneratorImpl' defined in file [E:\JAVA\BankEE\out\artifacts\BankEE_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\model\bl\NumberGeneratorImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1216)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$3.call(StandardContext.java:5279)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
at     org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:123)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean
```

now i gonna show you my app classes and interface:

this is INumberGenerator Interface:

```
public interface INumberGenerator {

public String returnNumber();
}
```

this is NumberGeneratorImpl(in this class because of @Repository give me ERROR):

```
@Repository
public class NumberGeneratorImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements INumberGenerator {

@Override
@Transactional
public String returnNumber() {
    List<String> list = getHibernateTemplate().find("select n.number from NumberGenerator n ");
    Integer newNumber = Integer.parseInt(list.get(0))+1;
    getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("update NumberGenerator n set n.number=?",newNumber.toString());
    return list.get(0);
}
```

}

and this is my controller(Spring-mvc):

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    INumberGenerator numberGenerator;

 @RequestMapping(//something)
 public String test(//request and response)
  {
     numberGenerator.returnNumber();


 }
```

at the end this is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
"default-autowire="byName">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="model.bl"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>


<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">


</bean>
<bean id="driverManagerDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bankee"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="myjava123"/>

</bean>
<bean id="localSessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="driverManagerDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
   <list>
        //hbm definitions
   </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>

            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="numberGenerator" class="model.bl.NumberGeneratorImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactoryBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactoryBean" />
</bean>


</beans>
```

can anybody tell me what is the problem that @Repository makes???
the error will gone when i delete @Repository

Comment: You need to autowire numbergeneratorImpl not numberGenerator

Comment: sorry but same error again

Comment: At the bottom of your stack i.e. the first error is about the hibernate template. Have you got a template setup with annotation @. Because I am watching this after a while, I might not remember correctly, but I am pretty sure a hibernate JpaDaoSupport thingy is required.

Comment: i use classic hibernate so i use HibernateDAOSupport instead of jpaDaoSupport

Comment: also i have classes like it with @Repository that they work fine

Comment: MadProgrammer's answer is the one I was talking about, should've mentioned that it's the xml servlet file :)

Comment: You have a component-scan that retrieve all @Repository, indeed the problem is for the bean "numberGeneratorImpl" that you haven't in your spring context. You must exclude it form component scan else you have 2 bean of NumberGeneratorImpl.class

Comment: @Xstian so if i understand correctly ,you mean that i have two bean definition : 1)with Component-scan 2)with my explicit bean tag and i must  use one of them . am i right?

Comment: Yes, you've got it right :) For this reason the bean name is `numberGeneratorImpl` and not `numberGenerator`.

Comment: but with numberGenerator it works fine . is your suggestion for make style of context Standard ?

Comment: I think that you can remove the declaration of `numberGenerator` and use directly the other one `numberGeneratorImpl`. Maybe you can add a @Qualifier("numberGenerator") under @Repository in order to change the least possible.

Comment: @Xstian i have tried it but i get error that:"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: model.bl.IdeaManagerImple" so ithink i can not use it in this way but thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `component-scan` that retrieve all @Repository, indeed the problem is for the bean "numberGeneratorImpl" that you haven't in your spring context. You must exclude it form component scan else you have 2 bean of NumberGeneratorImpl.class

- `numberGeneratorImpl`
- `numberGenerator`

You've two way..

**First solution**

add in your context

```
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

remove below declaration

```
<bean id="numberGenerator" class="model.bl.NumberGeneratorImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

and modify

```
@Repository
@Qualifier("numberGenerator")
public class NumberGeneratorImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements INumberGenerator {
```

**Second solution**

Exclude the class from `component-scan`

```
<context:component-scan base-package="model.bl">
    <!--other filters-->
    <!--.......-->
    <context:exclude-filter expression="model\.bl\.NumberGeneratorImpl" type="regex" />
</context:component-scan>
```

I hope that it was helpful.

---

In adding .. the bean `hibernateTemplate` is not real necessary, when you use HibernateDaoSupport only one of `sessionFactory` or `hibernateTemplate` is required. You could also make an alias for your `localSessionFactoryBean`.

```
<alias name="localSessionFactoryBean" alias="sessionFactory" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think below line is missed in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

```
<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="localSessionFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: exactly than you very much !!